# Slick 3 MySQL RAND() and update

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-3.0

I want to update whole rows in table like this:

```
UPDATE tracks SET random_sorting = (CAST(RAND() * 100000 AS UNSIGNED) + 1)
```

But I don't know how to do it in Slick without iterating through each row.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using plain query `db.run(sqlu"UPDATE tracks SET random_sorting = (CAST(RAND() * 100000 AS UNSIGNED) + 1)")`